# CDI: Replacement for BeanManager.fireEvent()?

Tags: events, cdi

In a previous CDI version, there is a method on `javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager` called [fireEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#fireEvent-java.lang.Object-java.lang.annotation.Annotation...-) that allows you to programmatically fire off an ad hoc CDI event, rather than requiring you to inject an `Event` instance first.  In current CDI version, however, that method seems to have been removed (although it's still mentioned in the Jakarta EE Spec).  Is there a replacement for this method in current CDI version?  Is there a better way to perform this action in CDI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was deprecated since CDI 2.0. As usual, replacement of any deprecation is mentioned in the [javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/apidocs/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/beanmanager#fireEvent-java.lang.Object-java.lang.annotation.Annotation...-):

> This method is deprecated from CDI 2.0 and [`getEvent()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/2.0/apidocs/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/beanmanager#getEvent--) should be used instead.

It has been [removed](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.cdi/jakarta/enterprise/inject/spi/beanmanager) in CDI 4.0.

As per the javadoc where the deprecation was mentioned you should be using [`BeanManager#getEvent()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/4.0/apidocs/jakarta.cdi/jakarta/enterprise/inject/spi/beancontainer#getEvent()) instead.

So the old form of

```java
beanManager.fireEvent(event, qualifiers);
```

needs to be migrated to

```java
beanManager.getEvent().select(qualifiers).fire(event);
```

This new API allows you to fire the event asynchronously, which wasn't possible with old API.

```java
beanManager.getEvent().select(qualifiers).fireAsync(event);
```

Comment: This is correct - I'll just add that the reason for this is addition of async events in CDI 2.0. Through this new method (`BM#getEvent()`),  you perform all the config and then choose whether you want to fire the event in a sync or async manner.

Comment: Indeed, I've further clarified the answer on that, thanks!